# Python Websocket add "if" function in "on_message" without being delayed

Tags: python, websocket, delay

i have script like this

```
def on_message(ws, message):
   if str(message).split()[0] == '<open':
      print('Opening Game')
      print(message)
   elif str(message).split()[0] == '<start':
      print('Game Started')
      print(message)
   elif str(message).split()[0] == '<catch':
      print(message)
      if str(message).split()[2] == '1':
          #send catch value 1
      else:
          pass
   elif str(message).split()[0] == '<result':
      print(message)
      #result value of catch is '2'
   else:
      pass
```

and server send broadcast message like this

1. sending opening game
2. send start game
3. send random 'catch' value to client on range(1 - 100)

How can I set an condition for the next message that comes through on_message on a WebSocket stream without causing it to run on the current message?

Comment: not sure that i understand the question. possible to rephrase it and what you want to acheive or where the error is ?

Comment: @D.L thanks for reply, How can I set an condition for the next message that comes through on_message on a WebSocket stream without causing it to run on the current message?